# Moshi 1.9.1 Cannot serialize Kotlin type

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

I have a working code serializing/deserializing data using Moshi 1.8.0

Upgrading to 1.9.1 now leads to a crash when attempting to serialize:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot serialize Kotlin type
>   com.xxx.Spot. Reflective serialization of Kotlin classes without
>   using kotlin-reflect has undefined and unexpected behavior. Please use
>   KotlinJsonAdapter from the moshi-kotlin artifact or use code gen from
>   the moshi-kotlin-codegen artifact.

Here is the serializer code:

```
val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
val dataListType = newParameterizedType(List::class.java, T::class.java)
val adapter: JsonAdapter<List<T>> = moshi.adapter(dataListType)
val json = adapter.toJson(dataList)
```

and the corresponding T class is

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class Spot(
    var id: String = "",
    var localizedName: String? = null,
    var type: String = "",
    var location: Location? = null
)
```

I'm totally clueless about what to do here.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: show us the dependencies you are using

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to add @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true) before your data class

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true) 
data class Spot(
    var id: String = "",
    var localizedName: String? = null,
    var type: String = "",
    var location: Location? = null
)
```

Comment: Why is that needed?

Comment: ... and include the corresponding kapt config in your build. Details here: https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/README.md#kotlin

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Adding @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true) + changing the gradle implementation from 'moshi' to 'moshi-kotlin' + kapt did the trick

Comment: Even after using the JsonClass annotation and trying both the reflection method (moshi-kotlin gradle implementation) and the codegen method Moshi still threw the "Cannot Serialize" runtime exception. Has anyone else had trouble even after making these changes?

Comment: @Cody - do you have enums in the class that you want to serialize?

Comment: @rimes yep, i do

Comment: Then you need to exclude them from generating an adapter. Add this to the enum class @JsonClass(generateAdapter = false) and add this to the proguard file 
-keepclassmembers @com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass class * extends java.lang.Enum {
    <fields>;
    **[] values();
}

Here you can read about serializing enums with moshi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64068151/enum-parsing-fails-with-moshi-and-r8

Answer (score 21):

The other option if you don't want to add `@JsonClass` annotations all over the place is to add KotlinJsonAdapterFactory to the Moshi Builder.

```kotlin
val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .addLast(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()
```

This uses reflection and you need to add a dependency to `com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin` as explained here https://github.com/square/moshi#kotlin

Comment: Important to note that you need to use `.addLast()` instead of `.add()` for Moshi v1.12+, as per their github docs https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/README.md#kotlin

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress wild cards using `@JvmSuppressWildcards`.

like this

```
val adapter: JsonAdapter<List<@JvmSuppressWildcards T>> = moshi.adapter(dataListType)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add this annotation

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
```

to your data class to be like this

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true) 
data class Spot(
        var id: String = "",
        var localizedName: String? = null,
        var type: String = "",
        var location: Location? = null
     )
```

then you can use [Moshi kotlin extensions](https://github.com/mazenrashed/MoshiKotlinExtensions) to deserialize your json array like this:

```
val Spots: List<Spot>? = yourJson.deserializeList()
```