# Moshi 1.9.x Cannot serialize Kotlin type

Tags: android, json, robolectric, moshi

I'm running into the following crash and stack trace after upgrading to [Moshi 1.9.1](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-191) (from [1.8.0](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-180)):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot serialize Kotlin type com.garpr.android.data.models.RankedPlayer. Reflective serialization of Kotlin classes without using kotlin-reflect has undefined and unexpected behavior. Please use KotlinJsonAdapter from the moshi-kotlin artifact or use code gen from the moshi-kotlin-codegen artifact.
for class com.garpr.android.data.models.RankedPlayer
for class com.garpr.android.data.models.AbsPlayer

    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi$LookupChain.exceptionWithLookupStack(Moshi.java:349)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:150)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:98)
    at com.squareup.moshi.AdapterMethodsFactory$AdapterMethod.bind(AdapterMethodsFactory.java:313)
    at com.squareup.moshi.AdapterMethodsFactory.create(AdapterMethodsFactory.java:62)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:138)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:98)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:72)
    at com.garpr.android.data.converters.AbsPlayerConverterTest.setUp(AbsPlayerConverterTest.kt:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:546)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:252)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot serialize Kotlin type com.garpr.android.data.models.RankedPlayer. Reflective serialization of Kotlin classes without using kotlin-reflect has undefined and unexpected behavior. Please use KotlinJsonAdapter from the moshi-kotlin artifact or use code gen from the moshi-kotlin-codegen artifact.
    at com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.create(ClassJsonAdapter.java:83)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.nextAdapter(Moshi.java:169)
    at com.squareup.moshi.AdapterMethodsFactory$AdapterMethod.bind(AdapterMethodsFactory.java:312)
    at com.squareup.moshi.AdapterMethodsFactory.create(AdapterMethodsFactory.java:62)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:138)
    ... 23 more
```

I saw [this other Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58660364/moshi-1-9-1-cannot-serialize-kotlin-type), but it does not apply to me, as I've already added the relevant `@JsonClass(generateAdapter = X)` line to my classes.

I use a custom [`AbsPlayerConverter` class](https://github.com/charlesmadere/smash-ranks-android/blob/e7cd6e8d5ea80984b69701d50456ab11376cd2aa/smash-ranks-android/app/src/main/java/com/garpr/android/data/converters/AbsPlayerConverter.kt) for my [`AbsPlayer`](https://github.com/charlesmadere/smash-ranks-android/blob/e7cd6e8d5ea80984b69701d50456ab11376cd2aa/smash-ranks-android/app/src/main/java/com/garpr/android/data/models/AbsPlayer.kt) class, this is used so that I can determine which subclass to resolve to. And then, if it resolves to [`RankedPlayer`](https://github.com/charlesmadere/smash-ranks-android/blob/a66d118f33c23b7a655d10da21630f909abd3639/smash-ranks-android/app/src/main/java/com/garpr/android/data/models/RankedPlayer.kt), I use another custom converter for that ([`RankedPlayerConverter`](https://github.com/charlesmadere/smash-ranks-android/blob/a66d118f33c23b7a655d10da21630f909abd3639/smash-ranks-android/app/src/main/java/com/garpr/android/data/converters/RankedPlayerConverter.kt)).

Here is [my Moshi-builder code](https://github.com/charlesmadere/smash-ranks-android/blob/a66d118f33c23b7a655d10da21630f909abd3639/smash-ranks-android/app/src/main/java/com/garpr/android/koin/MiscModule.kt#L26):

```
Moshi.Builder()
        .add(AbsPlayerConverter)
        .add(AbsRegionConverter)
        .add(AbsTournamentConverter)
        .add(MatchConverter)
        .add(RankedPlayerConverter)
        .add(SimpleDateConverter)
        .build()
```

And here is Moshi in [my gradle file](https://github.com/charlesmadere/smash-ranks-android/blob/6a01556c71f17cc74c2f3c93d8c6b331535b20d1/smash-ranks-android/app/build.gradle#L131):

```
implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.9.1"
kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.9.1"
```

So finally, after all of that text and info, I have no idea how I can be running into this crash. I clearly have defined how to serialize/deserialize my `RankedPlayer` class. And if I downgrade to Moshi 1.8.0, and leave my codebase completely as-is, this crash goes away and everything works flawlessly.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: So did you follow the instructions in the error message? `Please use KotlinJsonAdapter from the moshi-kotlin artifact or use code gen from the moshi-kotlin-codegen artifact`

Comment: @ianhanniballake well I'm fairly certain that I have. I don't think I need to use `KotlinJsonAdapterFactory` as it's needed only if you aren't going to be using Moshi's codegen support. And the only places I don't use Moshi's codegen are with those 6 converter classes that I listed above. And none of this information on Moshi's reflection/codegen capabilities in [the readme](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/README.md) have changed since before 1.8.0, which when I downgrade to this version, all of my problems disappear.

Comment: The [Kotlin part of the readme](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/README.md#kotlin) makes it pretty clear that you need to add the `KotlinJsonAdapterFactory` if you're not using Moshi's codegen...like for those specific converters. That is absolutely something that changed in Moshi 1.9.X as per [the blog post about Moshi 1.9](https://www.zacsweers.dev/a-closer-look-at-moshi-1-9/). What makes you think that doesn't apply for your case?

Comment: @ianhanniballake you should put this as an Answer for upvoting and acceptance

Comment: @ianhanniballake I just didn't think I needed Moshi's Kotlin reflection capabilities because the documentation makes it sounds pretty optional, for example this line from [their readme](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/README.md#kotlin): "you may use reflection, codegen, or both". And since I didn't used to need it with `1.8.0`, I figured I was still okay without it... But  had never seen that blogpost you linked . I guess my feeling now is that they could be a bit more clear on this in the readme. Thank you for the help!!

Comment: @CharlesMadere you are right. Got stuck 2 hours just for a legacy documentation of 1.8

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The error message specifically says `Please use KotlinJsonAdapter from the moshi-kotlin artifact or use code gen from the moshi-kotlin-codegen artifact`

As per the [Kotlin part of the readme](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/README.md#kotlin), you must add the `KotlinJsonAdapterFactory` if you're not using Moshi's codegen. This was a specific behavior change in Moshi 1.9 as per [the blog post about Moshi 1.9](https://www.zacsweers.dev/a-closer-look-at-moshi-1-9/).

```
Moshi.Builder()
    .add(AbsPlayerConverter)
    .add(AbsRegionConverter)
    .add(AbsTournamentConverter)
    .add(MatchConverter)
    .add(RankedPlayerConverter)
    .add(SimpleDateConverter)
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()
```

And make sure you're using `implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.9.1")`

Comment: I don't understand this part "if you're not using Moshi's codegen"

Answer (score 26):

I'm using retrofit and I had to do the following:

In the build.grade:

```
implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$moshiVersion"
```

In my repository:

```
val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(WEB_SERVICE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .build()
```

Answer (score 8):

I got this when I forgot to add `@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)` to one of my classes.