# Enum parsing fails with moshi and R8

Tags: moshi

I have the following dependencies:

moshi-codegen: 1.10.0
kotlin: 1.4.10
Android Gradle Plugin: 4.0.1
R8 is enabled in the build.

At runtime, i got the following stacktrace when Moshi tries to parse enums

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Missing field in e.f.a.k.c.b.a
        at com.squareup.moshi.StandardJsonAdapters$EnumJsonAdapter.<init>(SourceFile:246)
        at com.squareup.moshi.StandardJsonAdapters$1.create(SourceFile:67)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:141)
        at com.tsystems.tpay.data.client.models.ContactApiModelJsonAdapter.<init>(SourceFile:30)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at com.squareup.moshi.internal.Util.generatedAdapter(SourceFile:553)
        at com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory.create(SourceFile:193)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:141)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:101)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:71)
        at com.squareup.moshi.CollectionJsonAdapter.newArrayListAdapter(SourceFile:52)
        at com.squareup.moshi.CollectionJsonAdapter$1.create(SourceFile:36)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:141)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(SourceFile:101)
        at p.z.a.a.a(SourceFile:91)
        at p.u.a(SourceFile:352)
        at p.u.b(SourceFile:335)
        at p.k.a(SourceFile:113)
        at p.k.a(SourceFile:82)
        at p.v.a(SourceFile:37)
        at p.u.a(SourceFile:192)
        at p.u$a.invoke(SourceFile:149)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
        at $Proxy14.c(Unknown Source)
        at e.f.a.k.b.f$g.a(SourceFile:87)
        at i.b0.j.a.a.b(SourceFile:33)
        at j.a.v0.run(SourceFile:241)
        at j.a.g3.a.a(SourceFile:594)
        at j.a.g3.a.a(SourceFile:60)
        at j.a.g3.a$b.run(SourceFile:740)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: PERSONAL
        at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1604)
        at com.squareup.moshi.StandardJsonAdapters$EnumJsonAdapter.<init>(SourceFile:240)
```

According to the [README](https://github.com/square/moshi#r8--proguard), i do not have to add R8 rules manually, but maybe enums are exceptions?

Comment: Can you check you mapping file - what proguard did with your enum class?

Comment: Basically, moshi fails here https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/moshi/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/StandardJsonAdapters.java#L277. That gives me impression enum should not be obfuscated. I'm trying to find moshi proguard configuration. Can you check in the library jar?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes enum should be treated a bit differently and there is currently a pending PR to update the README file (as of the time of writing) https://github.com/square/moshi/pull/1216.

You have 2 options:

1. Add `@JsonClass(generateAdapter = false)` on top of your enum definition.
2. Add a proguard rule to keep your enum's fields e.g.,

```
-keepclassmembers enum your.model.package.YourEnum {
    <fields>;
    **[] values();
}
```

**Reason:**

According to the code here https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/0c85eae34af00ecbee46beaa5b25fb4af00fb9f2/moshi/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/moshi.pro#L10, Enum field names are used by the integrated `EnumJsonAdapter`. Also `values()` is synthesized by the Kotlin compiler and is used by `EnumJsonAdapter` indirectly.

Also note on the same file that Moshi has generated a pre-made proguard rule which is inherited by your app:

```
-keepclassmembers @com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass class * extends java.lang.Enum {
    <fields>;
    **[] values();
}
```

This rule is basically applied to all classes annotated by the `@JsonClass` annotation, so if you add the annotation (Option#1), your class would be covered by this rule.

Alternatively if you don't want adding the annotation, you can add the rule specifically for your class aka Option#2.

Answer (score 0):

When using EnumJsonAdapterFactory for parsing enums, you must add `-keep class your.package.name.EnumIntSafeJsonAdapter { *; }` in proguard-rules.pro of app's build.gradle. Otherwise, there is a possibility to face the error: "Unable to create converter for class $yourEnumClass", especially for gradle 8 and upwards where android.enableR8.fullMode is enabled by default